# Drupal blog entry programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, blogs

I'm trying to make a blog entry programmatically using this code.

```
$node->title = $_POST['title'];
$node->created = time();
$node->changed = time();
$node->status = 1; //published
$node->comment=1;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->language='en';
$node->body = $_POST['content'];
$node->type = 'blog';
node_save($node);
print_r($node);
```

The node gets created on the database but when I open the blog entry on the website it doesn't show the body. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this didnt blow up??? Wow. That's surprising. I would try `$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $_POST['content'];`  because body is a text field now.

Comment: It was hardly worth keeping my answer after I'd changed it per your suggestions so I've deleted it. Thanks for the tips I'd always wondered if it was necessary to clean input before adding data to a field in this way, I've never delved into that part of core :)

Comment: ok now i get this error
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-80-0-0-en' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: ITS ALIVE!!!! it works, i've tested it on another DB and it working just fine... there must b something wrong in mine, Thank you so mutch !